# ZnSecureServer on Pharo3.0 on Ubuntu

Tags: pharo

I'm trying to start a https server using this code in Pharo3.0 on ubuntu 14.04 32bit (but I've also tried on 64bit):

```
(ZnSecureServer on: 8343 )
    certificate: '/home/monty/monty-cert.pem';
    logToTranscript;
    start;
    yourself.
```

I get this error:
    SSL Exception: accept failed [code:-5]

Has anyone gotten this to work on Pharo3.0 on linux?  If so, how?
Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works on my 3.0

```
(ZnSecureServer on: 1235)
    certificate: '/home/philippeback/.ssh/server.pem';
    logToTranscript;
    start;
    yourself.
```

Certificate created with:

```
openssl genrsa -out privkey.pem 1024
openssl req -new -key privkey.pem -out certreq.csr
# makes certreq.csr  privkey.pem
openssl x509 -req -days 3650 -in certreq.csr -signkey privkey.pem -out newcert.pem
# should say Signature ok / Getting Private key 
( openssl x509 -in newcert.pem; cat privkey.pem ) > server.pem
```

Some screenshots

[image: Accessing the server]
[image: Pharo Side]

Comment: Thanks!  You nailed it.  I didn't do the last step when generating the key:  ( openssl x509 -in newcert.pem; cat privkey.pem ) > server.pem.  Once I did that it worked!  Really appreciate your help!